# Delphi Clipboard and Graphics DCU's Missing

Tags: api, delphi, delphi-xe4

I have this weird thing that keeps happening when trying to use the following unit:

`XLSReadWriteII 5`

Every time I add one of their components to my form and compile it, it gives me the following error:

`[dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(16): F1026 File not found: 'C:\Users\Gordon\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\grdi\Clipbrd.dcu'`

This tells me that there is no DCU's in my API, no I get the same error on my windows 7 and my windows 8 pc's. Delphi was installed from the embarcadero website via their installer.

If I download a clipboard.dcu and .pas file and run it again it gives me the same error saying Graphics.duc is missing...

I have emailed the company `Axolot Data` (the creators of XLSReadWrite 5) with regards to this issue, they just keep telling me my API is corrupt, on both pc's??

However what I find strange is that their supplied samples run.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution or reason this is happening.

`XLSReadWrite` 5 is a VCL component which references the VCL API, im using FMX.

The package was designed for VCL and not FMX but for some reason shows up in the FMX Units.

Strange but that might be my cause

Comment: Correct, you cannot reference VCL units or units with VCL dependencies in a FMX unit. However there is a way to mix the two on Windows. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643260/how-to-have-both-vcl-and-fmx-in-one-application