# How to embed a FireMonkey form in a VCL form seamlessly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, firemonkey

I used the trick described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315050/delphi-xe2-possible-to-instantiate-a-firemonkey-form-in-vcl-application) to display a FireMonkey form on a TPanel in a VCL application. My problem is that clicking (controls on) the embedded form causes the VCL form (containing that TPanel) to become deactivated. The most obvious consequence of that is the window border changing color all the time.

When displaying a VCL form on a TPanel of another, this doesn't happen; the forms apparently "merge". What should I do to reach a similar result with FireMonkey? I want controls on the FireMonkey form to be usable, but keep the parent form activated.

## Update 1

### VCL

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, FMX.Forms, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, FMX.Platform.Win;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses FireMonkeyForms;

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LFMForm: FireMonkeyForms.TForm1;
  LFMHWnd: HWND;
begin
  LFMForm := FireMonkeyForms.TForm1.Create(nil);
  LFMForm.Left := 0;
  LFMForm.Top := 0;
  LFMForm.Height := Panel1.ClientHeight;
  LFMForm.Width := Panel1.ClientWidth;
  LFMForm.BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle.bsNone;
  LFMForm.BorderIcons := [];
  LFMHWnd := FmxHandleToHWND(LFMForm.Handle);
  SetWindowLong(LFMHWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(LFMHwnd, GWL_STYLE) or WS_CHILD);
  Winapi.Windows.SetParent(LFMHWnd, Panel1.Handle);
  LFMForm.Visible := True;
end;

end.
```

### FireMonkey

```
unit FireMonkeyForms;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the behavior is that the window manager does not know you have made your firemonkey window a child, hence it is deactivating the previously active window when you activate the firemonkey window. As is documented in [`SetParent function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have to set the *child* flag manually. An example usage could be:

```
var
  FMForm: TFMForm1;
  FMHWnd: HWND;
begin
  FMForm := TFMForm1.Create(nil);
  FMForm.Left := 0;
  FMForm.Top := 0;

  FMHWnd := FmxHandleToHWND(FMForm.Handle);
  SetWindowLong(FMHWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(FMHwnd, GWL_STYLE) or WS_CHILD);
  winapi.windows.SetParent(FMHWnd, Panel1.Handle);
  FMForm.Visible := True;
```

**Update:**
If you have to remove the fmx form's borders, setting `BorderStyle` sets the `WS_POPUP` style which you cannot use with `WS_CHILD`. In that case set the styles you need explicitly instead of getting and 'or'ring them. F.i.

```
  ..
  LFMForm.BorderIcons := [];
  LFMForm.BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle.bsNone;
  LFMHWnd := FmxHandleToHWND(LFMForm.Handle);
  SetWindowLong(LFMHWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILDWINDOW or WS_BORDER);
  ..
```

Comment: Tried exactly this, but the effect remains.

Comment: @tvdien - I could duplicate your problem with a brand new project and this piece resolves it there. Your code is probably different, if you can include a simple duplicatable case in your question, it would help.

Comment: Posted the code. As far as I can tell, I'm doing exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @tvdien - It's setting the 'BorderStyle' that breaks it, it sets the WS_POPUP style (WS_CHILD cannot be used with WS_POPUP).

Comment: I xor'ed with WS_POPUP, as an alternative to the update you posted. Either way, thanks a lot for your efforts! I didn't expect to have this resolved (for me) so quickly.

Comment: Hmm, now a new problem came up, that keyboard input doesn't come through. Mouse clicks do work. Enabled TabStop, but that didn't change anything. With the border present, it does work. Your answer is accepted anyway, but if you feel like it, any further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @tvdien - Can't think of anything right now, if it were a VCL form probably InsertControl would help... Consider asking a new question.